# one to many - values become result columns

Tags: sql, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Assume I have two tables related with one to many:

```
Person:
  - name
  - age
  - phone
```

```
Attributes:
  - fk
  - field
  - value
```

for example

Person:

| id | name | age | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 18 | `null` |
| 2 | Sue | 22 | 1234567890 |
| 3 | Linda | 31 | 9876543210 |

Attributes:

| id | fk | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | hair | brown |
| 2 | 1 | eyes | blue |
| 3 | 2 | hair | black |
| 4 | 3 | height | 6 |

Is it possible to create a query with a result that looks like this:

| name | age | phone | hair | eyes | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 18 | `null` | brown | blue | `null` |
| Sue | 22 | 1234567890 | black | `null` | `null` |
| Linda | 31 | 9876543210 | `null` | `null` | 6 |

Comment: Not a mysql user, but I don't think it supports `pivot` functions. You could write `conditional aggregation` case expressions for each attribute. Do you have known attributes, or does this need to be dynamic?

Comment: assume the attributes are all known.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `conditional aggregation`.

```
create table person (
  id integer, 
  name varchar(10), 
  age integer, 
  phone varchar(10)
  );
  
insert into person values 
(1, 'John', 18, null), 
(2, 'Sue', 22, '1234567890'), 
(3, 'Linda', 31, '9876543210'), 
(4, 'Seymore', 78, null);

create table attributes (
  id integer, 
  fk integer, 
  field varchar(20), 
  value varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into attributes values 
(1, 1, 'hair', 'brown'), 
(2, 1, 'eyes', 'blue'), 
(3, 2, 'hair', 'black'), 
(4, 3, 'height', '6');
```

---

```
select  
  p.name, 
  p.age, 
  p.phone, 
  max(case when a.field = 'hair' then a.value else null end) as hair, 
  max(case when a.field = 'eyes' then a.value else null end) as eyes, 
  max(case when a.field = 'height' then a.value else null end) as height
from person p
left join attributes a
  on p.id = a.fk
group by p.name, p.age, p.phone;
```

| name | age | phone | hair | eyes | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 18 |  | brown | blue |  |
| Sue | 22 | 1234567890 | black |  |  |
| Linda | 31 | 9876543210 |  |  | 6 |
| Seymore | 78 |  |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJmgYpAsQTAxkqrxM2boMN/0)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `pivot` as far as I am aware, but if this does not need to have a dynamic amount of attributes, you could self join `Attributes` via `left join`, and filter the joins to the attributes needed:

```
select p.name
    , p.age
    , p.phone
    , hair.value
    , eye.value
    , height.value
from Person p
left join Attributes hair
    on p.id = hair.fk
    and hair.field = 'hair'
left join Attributes eye
    on p.id = eye.fk
    and eye.field = 'eye'
left join Attributes height
    on p.id = height.fk
    and height.field = 'height'
```

If you do require a dynamic number of attributes, you can create a prepared statement, but I don't have an example of that readily available.

Comment: this is an interesting approach. I'll give it a try.